# Not able to check record is exist or not in standard set controller

Tags: apex, community

I have to check that the record exist in view List or not. So for this i wrote the following code for checking that records exist in list view or not.

```
  List<sObject> sobjectList=[select Name,Id from TestObj where Id='a0gG000000B8W2HIAV'];
  String query = 'Select Name from TestObj LIMIT 1';
  ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new   ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
  List<System.Selectoption> ListViewList=ssc.getListViewOptions();
  set<SObject> testset=new set<SObject>();
  List<sObject> listChildObject=null;
  for (System.Selectoption selopn : ssc.getListViewOptions()){
              string viewid,viewlabel;
              viewid=selopn.getValue();
              viewlabel=selopn.getlabel();
              ssc.setSelected(sobjectList);    
              ssc.setFilterId(viewid);                                                                       testset.addAll((List<sObject>)ssc.getSelected());

             }
             System.debug('testset-'+testset);
```

This above code is returning the testset is empty. Event this record exist in the list view of this user. 
But if i change the sequence like following:

ssc.setFilterId(viewid);
ssc.setSelected(sobjectList);

Now it will set records in each list view even though that records is not exist for this list view.

Actually i want to check that specific records exist in list view or not. I do not know which is best way to do in salesforce without iterating all records and checking.